# Cut off point in k-means clustering in sas

Tags: sas, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

So I want to classify my data into clusters with cut-off point in SAS. The method I use is k-means clustering. (I don't mind about the method, as long as, it gives me 3 groups.)

My code for clustering:

```
proc fastclus data=maindat outseed=seeds1 maxcluster =3 maxiter=0;
var value resid;
run;
```

I have the problem with the output result. I want the cut-off point for the Value to be include in the output file. (I don't want the cut-off point for Resid). So is there anyway to do this in SAS?

Edit: As Joe point out, I can't achieve what i'm looking for by using k-mean clustering. So is there another way? Basically, I want a cut-off point so that I can apply it to the another data set.

What I have:

```
Cluster  Value      Resid
 1        34        11.7668
 2        38.9      0.5328
 3        42.625    -13.2364
```

what I want:

```
Cluster  Value      Resid       Cut-off Value (Interger)
 1        34        11.7668     1-36
 2        38.9      0.5328      36-40
 3        42.625    -13.2364    40-44
```

My data:

```
data maindat;
input  value Resid ;
datalines;
44  -4.300511714
44  -9.646920963
44  -15.86956805
43  -16.14857235
43  -13.05797186
43  -13.80941206
42  -3.521394503
42  -1.102526302
42  -0.137573583
42  2.669238665
42  -9.540489193
42  -19.27474303
42  -3.527077011
41  1.676464068
41  -2.238822314
41  4.663079037
41  -5.346920963
40  -8.543723186
40  0.507460641
40  0.995302284
40  0.464194011
39  4.728791571
39  5.578685423
38  2.771297564
38  7.109159247
37  15.96059456
37  2.985292226
36  -4.301136971
35  5.854674875
35  5.797294021
34  4.393329025
33  -6.622580905
32  0.268500302
27  12.23062252
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could necessarily do this completely.

k-means clustering uses euclidean distance between all of the variables you provide it.  This means that it's not solely using `value` to cluster observations: it's using `Resid` as well.

As such, it's possible a row with a `value` that seems like it should go with cluster 2 should actually go with cluster 3, if the `Resid` value is much closer there.

In your example, if you request an `out` dataset, you will see this is true.  A proc freq of that out dataset reveals that cluster 1 has three rows, with values `27`, `37`, and `38`.  Cluster 2 has almost all of the rows - all but 7 in total - ranging from `32` to `44`.  Cluster 3 ranges from `40` to `44`.

As such, there's no reasonable way to define your clusters the way you ask with this method of clustering.  Clusters are typically defined by their centroid, and that's what you get with the `outstat` dataset; you can determine which cluster a particular value should be assigned based on this.

Comment: Yeah, I just realize that too after reading on my textbook.
Do you think there's any technique I can use other than clustering?

Comment: I haven't a clue what you're trying to do.  Are you just dividing into thirds based on `value`?

Comment: Right. I want to cluster it into three interval. 
Something's like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179983/automated-grouping-in-sas-with-minimizing-variance-within-group?noredirect=1#comment46581266_29179983
I'm just not sure how correct is this algorithm (mathematically).